# Why is my JS function parameter is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a script loading accepting friend requests and my onclick function is :

```
onclick="acceptfriendrequest('John');"
```

More details :

```
echo  "<br><div style='width:100%; height: 30px;'><div class='userpic' style='background-image: url($avatar); margin-left: 10px; float: left;'></div><p class='incomingfriendrequests' style='float: left; margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 8px;'>$usernames</p><input type='submit' onclick='acceptfriendrequest($usernames)' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='accept' value='Accept'><input type='submit' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='deny'onclick='declinefriendrequest($usernames)'  value='Deny'></div>";
```

But for some reason my console says : Uncaught ReferenceError: John is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick.

This is the function it links to :

```
function acceptfriendrequest(username) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("username", username);
  fd.append("accept", true);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fullurl = '../backend/friends.php';
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        loadfriends();
      };
  };
  xhr.send(fd);


}
```

Plz help

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `acceptfriendrequest(John)` ? ...

Comment: `and my onclick function is` can you show exactly how this is in code ... because `onclick="acceptfriendrequest('John');"` on its own makes no sense

Comment: Even removing the '' doesn't work.

Comment: `onclick='acceptfriendrequest($usernames)` ... see, `$usernames` isn't `'John'` ... lack of `'` for a start

Comment: I added the '' to test it, but that isn't the problem

Comment: `removing the '' doesn't work` no, you need to HAVE them

Comment: Ok, then I'll add them, but even with them it doesn't work

Comment: Try `onclick='acceptfriendrequest(\"$usernames\")'`.

Comment: `echo  "... onclick='acceptfriendrequest(\"$usernames\")' ...";`

Comment: And It's tough to add the '' because it is being echoed as : echo "... onclick=''johnstuff''"

Comment: What is in your array (is it an array) $usernames in your PHP? It sounds as though it is an array but you are talking of passing a single name *'John' and the function acceptfriendrequest seems to expecting a single username, not usernames.

Comment: Because my code goes gets all of the friend requests from the database then says : foreach ($result) {echo ...}

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have posted an answer though the problem was spotted also by others and  @Jaromanda X way of adding the quotes is better really than what I've used except I wanted to spell our what was going on in adding quotes around the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this clear for you :)

- in HTML onclick you need to put function without any arguments or () :

  ```
   // function without () or arguments
   onclick=acceptfriendrequest
  ```
- in JavaScript make arguments in variables out of function and then use this variables in your function as arguments :

  ```
  // variables as argument     
  let username = "Name";

  // function without arguments
  function acceptfriendrequest() {

    // use variables in function :)
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("username", username);
    fd.append("accept", true);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fullurl = '../backend/friends.php';
    xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        loadfriends();
      };
  };
  ```

Comment: This answer has not determined why his code is not working. In the future if someone has a similar problem they won't know how to solve it from your answer.

Comment: Yes. You have obviously been helpful and potentially gave him a solution to work with but it would be helpful if it was accompanied with details on why the error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In dev tools looking at the code generated by the PHP it gives this (assuming $usernames='John' in the PHP, and is only one name, not an array)

`<br><div style='width:100%; height: 30px;'><div class='userpic' style='background-image: url(); margin-left: 10px; float: left;'></div><p class='incomingfriendrequests' style='float: left; margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 8px;'>John</p><input type='submit' onclick='acceptfriendrequest(John)' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='accept' value='Accept'><input type='submit' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='deny'onclick='declinefriendrequest(John)'  value='Deny'></div>)`

Look at the calls to acceptfriendrequest and declinefriendrequest. They have John in there, not a string and it needs to be a string as several commentators have noted one way or another.

It is the PHP that needs changing, the onclick='acceptfriendrequest($usernames)' needs to have quotes added.

Here is the altered PHP echo - I have split elements onto newlines to make things a bit clearer and have added the necessary quotes in a basic way to show what is going on:

```
echo  "<br><div style='width:100%; height: 30px;'>
        <div class='userpic' style='background-image: url($avatar); margin-left: 10px; float: left;'></div>
        <p class='incomingfriendrequests' style='float: left; margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 8px;'>$usernames</p>
        <input type='submit' onclick='acceptfriendrequest(".'"'.$usernames.'"'.")' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='accept' value='Accept'>
        <input type='submit' style= 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px; float: left;' name='deny'onclick='declinefriendrequest(".'"'.$usernames.'"'.")'  value='Deny'>
        </div>";
```